# in foundation 5 when I change the ranges in settings it does not work

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I use these in my settings

```css
$small-range: (0em, 31em); /* 0, 640px */
$medium-range: (31.063em, 64em); /* 641px, 1024px */
$large-range: (64.063em, 90em); /* 1025px, 1440px */
$xlarge-range: (90.063em, 120em); /* 1441px, 1920px */
$xxlarge-range: (120.063em); /* 1921px */
```

All other settings compile correctly.
The above ones are simply ignored

Comment: How do you know if they're ignored? This seems to be the foundation for all containers on your site.

Comment: meta.foundation-mq-small{font-family:"/only screen and (max-width: 40em)/";width:0em}meta.foundation-mq-medium{font-family:"/only screen and (min-width:40.063em) and (max-width:64em)/";width:40.063em}

Comment: Can you show your sass structure?

Answer (score 3):

In you app.scss file, change the order of the imports to:

```css
@import "foundation/settings"; 
@import "foundation";
```

Make also sure that all paths are correct.

You can now choose the ranges as wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You have to uncomment some other variables to change media queries.

Find and uncomments below variables:

```
$screen: "only screen";

$landscape: "#{$screen} and (orientation: landscape)";
$portrait: "#{$screen} and (orientation: portrait)";

$small-up: $screen;
$small-only: "#{$screen} and (max-width: #{upper-bound($small-range)})";

$medium-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)})";
$medium-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($medium-range)})";

$large-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-range)})";
$large-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($large-range)})";

$xlarge-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xlarge-range)})";
$xlarge-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xlarge-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($xlarge-range)})";

$xxlarge-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xxlarge-range)})";
$xxlarge-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xxlarge-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($xxlarge-range)})";

$small: $small-up;
$medium: $medium-up;
$large: $large-up;
```

Answer (score 0):

One more thing needs to be uncommented in the _settings.scss file: @import "foundation/functions";

Source: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/891-media-query-ranges-doesnt-take-effect